# Capture horizontal touch movement while allowing native vertical scroll

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios, dom-events

I'm trying to explore how feasible it is to create an HTML5 interaction where a touch can be conditionally captured by the initial direction of the motion.

The goal is to capture and track the motion of the touch *only* if it initially moves in a horizontal direction. Combined with a responsive page layout which only scrolls vertically, we should be able to use horizontal swipe motion to do something cool by tracking it.

The problem is in the seeming impossibility (especially on iOS) of performing touch sequence capture *conditionally*.

In order to track a touch (and by this I mean specifically obtaining the stream of x,y coordinates which represent the position of the finger over time), `touchstart` has to be `preventDefault`ed in order to prevent the page from engaging native momentum-scroll. Native momentum-scroll, while in operation, suspends all JS execution (`setTimeout`, rAF, jQuery `animate` et al...) and even CSS keyframe/animation/transition execution.

I would really like to know if there's a way to somehow condition the `preventDefault()` of the original `touchstart` event. It's completely possible for JS to store that event object, and then not call it until some later time (when it is determined that we are indeed interested in preventing the native scroll from starting).

But this is certain to fail because the default behavior of not running `preventDefault()` on that event is to engage native-scroll, which then will block JS execution for the entire remaining duration of the scroll. Failing to return the event listener function attached to `touchstart` does not appear to be an option. It would freeze everything.

The tentative answer, then, without any additional insight, is that all swipes must be captured if we want to be able to capture it at all, and scrolling has to be "faked" via external means à la (iScroll)[http://cubiq.org/iscroll-5-ready-for-beta-test] (personally I would want to explore some sort kind of combination of rAF and `window.scrollTo` and would be surprised if iScroll 5 does not employ these APIs)

Incidentally the description for the 4th demo there got me really excited, but it turns out that all it does is create a page section that iScrolls horizontally while the rest of the page behaves regularly, which is entirely mundane.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`touch-action`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/touch-action#browser_compatibility), for which most values are supported by all browsers